# Is it beneficial to use triangle strips as opposed to triangles in OpenGL on iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

Are there benefits to using triangle strips as opposed to triangles on iOS? If I were to use triangle strips for drawing a quad, I would have to use 4 indices, but if I were to use just triangles, I would have to use 6 indices. Both would require 4 vertices.

Does iOS do anything under the hood to optimize triangle use and reduce memory so that using triangle strips won't actually provide a benefit? Is one method of drawing faster than the other?

(I am talking about using `glDrawElements` in conjunction with either `GL_TRIANGLES` or `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said it yourself, a triangle strip uses less data to convey the same information. The longer the strip, the more the gain.

Less data to send to the GPU = less time spent sending data = more time to make computations on it.